# Moving make-system for C cross-compiling using windows compiler from Cygwin to WSL2

Tags: c, powershell, makefile, wsl-2

I have inherited a make setup which runs in cygwin. For some targets uses a windows compiler, for others gcc.  I'm trying to get it to work in both Cygwin and WSL2-Ubuntu (20.4 LTS) - for the gcc targets WSL2 just works, but I'm having trouble with the windows executables in WSL2.

I've found that I can run the compiler from powershell via WSL2, so I thought - this will be easy. However when I call the compiler from make using the same command but with powershell.exe -c, it stalls.

```
CC := powershell.exe -c ../tools/bin/cc.exe

$(BUILD_DIR)/obj/%.o: $(PLATFORM_DIR)/%.c $(BUILD_DIR)/cc_depends
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CC_FLAGS) $(CC_DEFINES) -c $< -o $(PRODUCT_DIR)/$@
```

If I try to build this from WSL2 make, it stalls, and then I can see that the powershell.exe cc.exe process is just sitting there doing nothing.

If I run the same command (everything after powershell.exe -c) from a powershell.exe started in windows or WSL2 bash, it runs fine.   If I try to run the same command as a "one-off" in WSL2 Ubuntu with "powershell.exe -c ..." then it also stalls like in the make.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: More debugging seems to show that I can run the compiler as above with only --help for example. 

So it might be that the compiler is actually not liking some of the input  parameters.

Comment: Right, some more investigation and I think it's to do with the paths in the inludes to the compiler. 
I can run the compiler directly from WSL in make, so:
CC := ../tools/bin/cc.exe
and if I just run it with --help it still works. 
So something in the rest of the call is failing in Ubuntu WSL2, but works in cygwin.  I'll print them both and compare.

Comment: Is there a limit to the length of a command passed to a windows program from WSL2?

Comment: To add to the above question, I tried building up the compiler command and running it from the WSL command line, and it works up until the point where the number of characters exceeds 3834 characters.  If I just make up some build defines (-DTHING1 -DTHING2 etc) until it gets to 3834 characters, it works.  If I add one more non-white-space character, it fails.